# WordのVBAのコードについての質問です。

Tags: vba

#### やりたいこと

1. 塗りつぶし部分を指定して検索をかけて結果を蛍光ペンで色付けして確認。その後、Enterを押して次の塗りつぶし部分の検索をして蛍光ペンで色付けしてその都度確認していきます。
2. 直前に検出されて蛍光ペンで色付けされた部分は次の検索を行うためのEnterを押した時に元の塗りつぶしの色に戻していきます。

#### うまく動作しなかったコード

```
Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -553582746
```

を指定して検索したのですが、全ての部分に黄色の蛍光ペンがかかってしまいました。
VBA初心者です。ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Word VBA のコード

```
Sub findText()
 With Selection.Find
 .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -553582746
 .Execute
 Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
 Selection.MoveRight
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[【コード】括弧内の言葉をマーキングして読みやすくするWordマクロ（その3）](https://www.wordvbalab.com/code/12133/), [文字列をハイライト表示するWordテンプレート(3)](https://www.ka-net.org/ribbon/ri80.html), [ワードマクロで、表の行に色付けするVBAコードをご紹介します。](https://kirinote.com/wordvba-tablerowcolor/), [ワードマクロで、特定の文字を蛍光ペンで着色するVBAコードをご紹介します。](https://kirinote.com/wordvba-charcolouring/)

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決済み - [Word の VBAのコードについての質問です。](https://teratail.com/questions/288495)